# How to download php7.2-gd extension in ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: php, php-extension, php-gd

I want to install gd extension in my current php-project(php version is 7.2.34) for that i use this command `sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd` it's throwing following error and it's not showing in the list when i run `php -m` command ,How to install gd extension please help me to fix this issue..

`Error`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-gd : Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package depends on `libjpeg62-turbo` so you need to install it first

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
```

after that, you could install your package easily

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

Comment: It's showing libjpeg62-turbo-dev has no installation Candidate

Comment: i am facing similar problem while installing php7.2-curl also.                               
     php7.2-curl : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.44.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: install curl first `sudo apt install curl`

Comment: run `sudo apt install libcurl3`

Comment: it throws following error  E: Unable to locate package libcurl13

Comment: try this one `apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Comment: Is it compatible with php7.2-curl

Comment: I think so, but not sure

Comment: it is better to write a new question with the new problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69182135/how-to-download-or-install-php7-2-curl-extension-in-ubuntu-21-04  @joseph ,this is the new question for curl problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69182135/how-to-download-or-install-php7-2-curl-extension-in-ubuntu-21-04  @joseph ,this is the new question for curl problem